# Time to pad out some tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed whilst going through some tags that a lot of the tags do not have any context or description behind them

I think it is time we sorted this out

If you come across a tag that does not have a description please add one this will start to make this site a lot more fleshed and help people find the questions/answers that they need

Comment: Hi Jamie, thank you for your help with the tags!   I do want to note that tag wikis are not primarily to describe the tag term generally, but to describe how to correctly use the tag.  More detail [on meta here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one).

Comment: Ahh sweet I shall make edits appropriate now :)